# I want to send "Helo localhost" to a Smtp server with .NET (C# or VB)

Tags: c#, vb.net, smtp, smtpclient

In the current project, I'm asked to check connectivity to Smtp servers, via the response of "Helo" ("Ehlo" would be also fine, and actually, I could listen to any suggestion that could confirm connectivity anyway). I asked Google if there were some easy ways to do the equivalent of typing these simple two commands in C#. I have a little experience in some coding with `TcpClient`, so I know how to send strings as a byte data.

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
helo localhost
```

but..., NET's `SmtpClient` class doesn't seem to have a `Stream` member! In such a case, how I could sent some command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check Network Availablility VB.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947250/check-network-availablility-vb-net)

Comment: @MattWilko I think this question is more specific to a remote SMTP server rather than general network connectivity.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, my question rather be more about smtp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TcpClient` to connect to the remote port and then send the `helo localhost` command as a string of ASCII characters.

```
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);

        var stream = client.GetStream();

        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("localhost helo");

        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

However, I believe port 465 is for secure communications so you'll need to use SSL or use Port 25.

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't know about protocols and wasn't sure if TcpClient was the one I could use. I went with my ISP's smtp server instead of Gmail, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static class SmtpHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// test the smtp connection by sending a HELO command
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool TestConnection(Configuration config)
        {
            MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings = config.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;
            if (mailSettings == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("The system.net/mailSettings configuration section group could not be read.");
            }
            return TestConnection(mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host, mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Port);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// test the smtp connection by sending a HELO command
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="smtpServerAddress"></param>
        /// <param name="port"></param>
        public static bool TestConnection(string smtpServerAddress, int port)
        {
            IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(smtpServerAddress);
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList[0], port);
            using (Socket tcpSocket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                //try to connect and test the rsponse for code 220 = success
                tcpSocket.Connect(endPoint);
                if (!CheckResponse(tcpSocket, 220))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                // send HELO and test the response for code 250 = proper response
                SendData(tcpSocket, string.Format("HELO {0}\r\n", Dns.GetHostName()));
                if (!CheckResponse(tcpSocket, 250))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                // if we got here it's that we can connect to the smtp server
                return true;
            }
        }

        private static void SendData(Socket socket, string data)
        {
            byte[] dataArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            socket.Send(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        }

        private static bool CheckResponse(Socket socket, int expectedCode)
        {
            while (socket.Available == 0)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            byte[] responseArray = new byte[1024];
            socket.Receive(responseArray, 0, socket.Available, SocketFlags.None);
            string responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
            int responseCode = Convert.ToInt32(responseData.Substring(0, 3));
            if (responseCode == expectedCode)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
if (!SmtpHelper.TestConnection(ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)))
{
    throw new ApplicationException("The smtp connection test failed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for codes. Really appreciated. As it seems I need some time to understand your code, I'll go with answer way for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use C# [Telnet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telnet) to send commands `HELO <host>`.